# Alternating text like on Gumroad.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have seen this done a few times before. I can't remember the other sites, but if you know of others I'd like to see. (https://gumroad.com/)

Basically, when they do something like:

Share your 'songs' directly to your 'fans'. And the words in the quotes keep getting replaced.

I was wondering if there is a JS/Jquery library to help with that. Or otherwise I'd like some other websites that do it so I can get ideas!

Thanks.

Comment: Just wrote something like that but without the animations - http://jsfiddle.net/Dogbert/vF4rj/3/ You can add animations using [jQuery UI](http://api.jqueryui.com/drop-effect/).

Comment: Cool. Ya, that was helpful! If you submit that I'll accept.

Comment: Note your example website uses CSS animations, not jQuery UI.

Comment: animate function is JQuery, not JQuery UI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I implemented something similar (without animations) using jQuery.

The code basically cycles data from an array every 2000ms, and adds it to a span.

Live Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/Dogbert/vF4rj/3/

JS:

```
var options = [
    ["music", "listeners"],
    ["software", "users"],
    ["films", "viewers"],
    ["comics", "readers"]
];

var interval = 2000;

var holder1 = $(".holder-1"), holder2 = $(".holder-2");
var currentIndex = 0;

function doIt() {
    holder1.html(options[currentIndex][0]);
    holder2.html(options[currentIndex][1]);
    currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % options.length;
    setTimeout(doIt, interval);
}

doIt();
```

HTML:

```
<h2>
    Sell
    <span class="holder-1"></span>
    directly to your
    <span class="holder-2"></span>
</h2>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in their approach, it seems like this is what they are doing:

1. They have the header text in their code twice. One is what you see being animated. The other is hidden by setting its opacity to 0. This hidden version is what will be used to do any calculations on the displayed one.
2. The hidden version has its text updated by inserting new text into placeholder `span` tags. The displayed version has placeholders in that spot that are empty spaces, and their width is animated by using the new width from the hidden version.
3. The hidden version is also used to determine the positioning of the new text relative to the rest of the sentence, and based on that information, an HTML element containing that text is animated to fall in perfectly where it should.

A pretty clever approach.

Answer (score 0):

What makes this work for Gumroad is the slick animation so I feel answers are incomplete without this essential element.

That being said, the d3 javascript library (d3js.org) has a very good implementation of the base functionality plus support for transitions. The key code is the following which allows you to easily specify the type of css transform you want to be applied (see the last line):

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
         .attr("width", width)
         .attr("height", height)
         .append("g")
         .attr("transform", "translate(32," + (height / 2) + ")");
```

A full example can be viewed here: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808234